# Linq: Totals Groups By Month

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a simple business object:

```
Crime 
     Date
     PersonsInvolved
```

I need a list of total PersonsInvolved per month. The data is for 1 year so year doesn't need to be taken into account.

```
Jan 5
Feb 3
Mar 5
```

and so on

How is this done in Linq if I have an in memory collection like this:

```
List<Crime>() crimes;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var q =  from i in crimes
    group i by i.Date.ToString("MMM") into grp
    select new {Month = grp.Key, Count = grp.Sum(i => i.Persons)};
```

Answer (score 11):

```
crimes.GroupBy(c => c.Date.Month)
      .Select(g => new { Month = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Crime>() crimes = ...
var crimesPerMonth = crimes.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Month);
```